# Conditional rewrite in .htaccess based on domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have tried to use previous advice relating to similar questions, but without success.  It may be that the .htaccess file I am currently using is too complicated, and this is the source of my trouble.

Domain1 is in a subfolder of root, Domain1.  In my root folder I have the following .htaccess file, which works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain1.me.uk$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain1/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain1.me.uk$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ domain1/index.html [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.me.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1.me.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain1\.me\.uk" [R=301,L]
```

Domain2 is in another subfolder of root and I want .htaccess to rewrite conditionally to Domain1 if domain1.me.uk is the URL and to Domain2 if domain2.me.uk is the URL.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rewrite to **/domain1** folder when **domain1.me.uk** is in the url,you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1.me.uk$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain1/
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain1/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: That's great and much simpler!  And when I put another rewrite underneath it, both work.  Thank you!